# Old Bell & Howell Filmo 70HR 16mm camera

Tags: cable

I have two B&H Filmo 70HR 16mm film cameras that can use 400’ film magazines with the aid of motors to drive the take-up reel. One has a 24v motor and the other has a 110v motor. Both motors use 3 pin XLR female type power supply connectors. I’m comfortable building a cable to run from a 24v/5w power supply to the 3 pin female XLR power input connector, but using a standard “audio” XLR connector for 110v seems unwise because of the possibility of overheating. Is there a safe way to get from 110v Edison power plug to a female 3 pin XLR connector?

Comment: Are you sure it's *exactly* an XLR, or merely similar. I've been struggling to find any on Google now, but back in the 80s we had all our gear converted to use 'power cannons' - very similar to XLR, but not interchangeable. The male jack had a bare earth pin, but sheathed L/N. I don't still have any of that gear to be able to measure or photograph, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ah, i found them listed here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XLR_connector#Obsolete_patterns

Comment: If *is* a standard XLR, then this is a duplicate of https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/24973/use-xlr-for-power. But good catch if it isn't standard!